# How to get brand-children specific like count on Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying without much success to find how to retrieve the number of LIKES that a specific child page of a brand page in facebook has.

However, even though I can retrieve the the children and their IDs with:

```
/facebook/global_brand_children
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=facebook%2Fglobal_brand_children

The /likes still retrieves the GLOBAL number of likes for said global brand, instead of the number of likes for the SPECIFIC child page.

For example when viewing the return from the Facebook Japan page:

```
{
  "about": "Facebook Japanの公式ページです。", 
  "can_post": true, 
  "category": "Computers/internet website", 
  "checkins": 2, 
  "general_info": "http://www.facebook.com/FacebookJapan", 
  "is_published": true, 
  "talking_about_count": 979217, 
  "username": "FacebookJapan", 
  "website": "http://www.facebook.com/", 
  "were_here_count": 0, 
  "id": "365989369023", 
  "name": "Facebook", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/FacebookJapan", 
  "likes": 142245893, 
  "cover": {
    "cover_id": "10151895032999024", 
    "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1/s720x720/282842_10151895032999024_991535057_n.jpg", 
    "offset_y": 55, 
    "offset_x": 0
 }
}
```

Anyone got a clue how to approach this?
Thanks!

Comment: Child pages don't have a separate like count; all likes are associated with the global page. Also, the response you pasted shows `"likes": 142245893,`; 365989369023 is the ID.

Comment: Oops, thanks for pointing it out - edited. I was hoping this wouldn't be the case or that anyone knows a way to approach the problem differently... I'll keep researching I guess